# Titlesec numberless section numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

I've run into a problem where with using `titlesec` where my numberless sections are numbered. I took a look at a few other questions here, and the `titlesec` package help, where I saw the numberless option. However, with the suggestion that I noticed elsewhere here, i.e., to use `\sectioning` as the label it still produces a (wrong) number before the section name.

Can anyone give me a pointer here?

The present lines in my code read as:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,headheight=72pt,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,array,floatflt,graphicx,marvosym,multirow,subcaption,siunitx,tabu,titlesec,tocbibind,tocloft}
\usepackage[font=small,hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage[authoryear,round,sort,nonamebreak]{natbib}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

% keep this as last usepackage%
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pagebackref=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,breaklinks]{hyperref}


\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}{}{0em}{\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}{}{0em}{\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}}
```

And the endresult here is that all sections manage to change their font, size, and spacing, but that the ones that go by `\section*{}` are erroneously numbered.

I have my suspicion that I could do something by the optional `titlesec` commands, but I a not entirely confident in how they work.

Cheers

Comment: You have `\thesection` also in the `numberless` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `\thesection` the definition for `numberless`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large}

\begin{document}

\section*{Unnumbered section}

Some text

\section{Numbered section}

\end{document}
```

[image]