# Center Acronym Title and remove List of Tables / List of Figures from the Summary

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, glossaries, acronyms

Bom dia,

Preciso de ajuda com dois problemas:

O primeiro deles é com o titulo do Acronym, preciso que ele fique centralizado, `\Large` e com o espaçamento de 1cm igual o que já está configurado para o `\listoftables` (abaixo falo dele). Quanto ao Acronym, utilizei o pacote `\usepackage[acronym,style=super,nonumberlist]{glossaries}` com o arquivo de abreviaturas separadas, depois eu só importo ele.

> *Good Morning,*
>
> *I need help with two problems:*
>
> *The first one is with the Acronym title, I need it to be centered, `\ Large` and with the spacing of 1cm equal to what is already configured
> for `\ listoftables` (below I speak of it). As for Acronym, I used the
> `\ usepackage [acronym, style = super, nonumberlist] {glossaries}`
> package with the separate abbreviation file, then I just import it.*

[image]

Aqui está o titulo do `\listoftables` e é exatamente assim que eu preciso do Acronym, nesse eu utilizei o
`\usepackage{tocloft}`, `\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Large\bfseries\vspace{1cm}}` e  `\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}`:

> *Here is the title of `\ listoftables` and this is exactly how I need
> Acronym, in this I used `\ usepackage {tocloft}`, `\ renewcommand {\ cftlottitlefont} {\ hspace * {\ fill} \ Large \ bfseries \ vspace {1cm}}` and `\ renewcommand {\ cftafterlottitle} {\ hspace * {\ fill}}`:*

[image]

Mas não consigo uma forma de aplicar esta configuração para o Acrônimo.

E o segundo problema é que eu não consigo tirar a lista de Figuras e a lista de Tabelas do Sumário, achei umas soluções mas não deu certo, gera erros na compilação.

> *But I can't find a way to apply this setting to the Acronym.*
>
> *And the second problem is that I can't remove the list of Figures and
> the list of Tables from the Summary, I found some solutions but it
> didn't work, it generates errors in the compilation.*

[image]

Entendo só o básico do latex. Ficarei muito grato se alguém conseguir me dar esse helpzão. Obrigado

Arquivos:

> *I understand only the basics of latex. I will be very grateful if
> someone can give me that help. Thank you*
>
> *Files:*

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, openany, a4paper, english, brazil]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Large\bfseries\vspace{1cm}}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig,subfig}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\usepackage[acronym,style=super,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\small\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\renewcommand{\headwidth}{16cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase,relsize}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\scshape\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.2em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.4em}{}

\titlespacing*
    {\section}
    {0cm}
    {0.6em}
    {0.6em}

\usepackage[abnt-emphasize=bf,alf]{abntex2cite}

\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{quoting}
\newenvironment{citacao}
    {
        \setlength\parindent{0cm}
        \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
        \begin{quoting}[rightmargin=0cm,leftmargin=4cm]
    }
    {
        \end{quoting}
    }

\usepackage{titletoc}
\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill Sumário\hfill\vspace{1cm}}}

\titlecontents{section}
[0cm]
{}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace{0.5em}}
{}
{ \titlerule*[1pc]{. . . . .}\contentspage \nobreak}

\titlecontents{subsection}
[0.7cm]
{}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace{0.5em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{. . . . .}\contentspage \nobreak}

\include{conf/dados}

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

%%%%%%
%   Parte pré-textual
%%%%%%
\singlespacing

\include{pag/capa}
\include{pag/pre/folha-rosto}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{pag/pre/abreviacoes}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

%%%%%%
%   Parte textual
%%%%%%

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}\hspace{0.2em}-{}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\justify
\onehalfspacing
\setlength\parindent{1.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.6em}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\section[Introdução]{Introdução}
\input{pag/text/introducao}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\section[Justificativa]{Justificativa}
\input{pag/text/justificativa}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\section[Problema a ser resolvido]{Problema a ser resolvido}
\input{pag/text/Problema}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\section[Objetivos]{Objetivos}
\input{pag/text/Objetivos}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\section[Fundamentação Teórica]{Fundamentação Teórica}
\input{pag/text/fundamentacaoTeoria}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\section[Metodologia]{Metodologia}
\input{pag/text/metodologia}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\section[Cronograma]{Cronograma}
\input{pag/text/cronograma}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\section[Orçamento]{Orçamento}
\input{pag/text/orcamento}
\endgroup

%%%%%%
%   Parte pós-textual
%%%%%%

\newpage

\singlespacing

\begin{flushleft}
    \begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \bibliography{pag/pos/referencias}
    \endgroup
\end{flushleft}

\vspace{3cm}
\begin{flushright}
    \rule{6cm}{1pt} \\
    \autor

    \vspace{1cm}
    \rule{6cm}{1pt} \\
    \orientador
    
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

**abreviacoes.tex**

```
\printglossary[title=Lista de Abreviaturas e Siglas, type=\acronymtype]

\newacronym{aasi}{AASI}{Aparelhos de amplificação sonora individual}
\newacronym{sus}{SUS}{Sistema Único de Saúde}
\newacronym{bjorl}{BJORL}{Brazilian Journal}
\newacronym{iffar}{IFFar}{Instituto Federal Farroupilha}
\newacronym{oled}{OLED}{Organic light-emitting diode}
\newacronym{tic}{TIC}{Tecnologias da informação e comunicação}
\newacronym{mp3}{MP3}{MPEG-1/2 Audio Layer 3}
\newacronym{oms}{OMS}{Organização Mundial da Saúde}
\newacronym{db}{dB}{Decibéis}
\newacronym{dba}{dBA}{Decibéis escala A (Ruído continuo)}
\newacronym{dbc}{dBC}{Decibéis escala C (Ruído impulsivo)}
\newacronym{pa2h}{Pa2h}{Taxa de medição de exposição}
\newacronym{who}{WHO}{World Health Organization}
\newacronym{pc}{PC}{Personal Computer}
\newacronym{caa}{CAA}{Comunicação ampliada e alternativa}
\newacronym{csa}{CSA}{Comunicação suplementar e alternativa}
\newacronym{tdd}{TDD}{Telecommunication Devices for the Deaf}
\newacronym{pcs}{PCS}{Picture Communication Symbols}
\newacronym{eustat}{EUSTAT}{Empowering Users Through Assistive Technology}
\newacronym{lcd}{LCD}{Liquid Crystal Display}
\newacronym{cm}{cm}{Centímetro}
\newacronym{dsam}{DSAM}{Dispositivo Sensorial de Auxílio à Mobilidade}
\newacronym{feceesp}{FeCEESP}{Feira de Ciências das Escolas Estaduais de São Paulo}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I simplified your code, removing code irrelevant to the issue at hand.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, openany, a4paper, english, brazil]{article}


\usepackage{tocloft}


\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill Sumário\hfill~}}

\usepackage[acronym,style=super,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries



\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\scshape\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.2em}{}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{}{0.2em}{}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146522/titlesec-numberless-section-numbering


\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.4em}{}

\titlespacing*
    {\section}
    {0cm}
    {0.6em}
    {0.6em}

\usepackage[abnt-emphasize=bf,alf]{abntex2cite}

\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{quoting}
\newenvironment{citacao}
    {
        \setlength\parindent{0cm}
        \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
        \begin{quoting}[rightmargin=0cm,leftmargin=4cm]
    }
    {
        \end{quoting}
    }

\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}

\newacronym{oms}{OMS}{Organização Mundial da Saúde}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%   Parte pré-textual
%%%%%%
\printglossary[title=Lista de Abreviaturas e Siglas, type=\acronymtype]

\section{asdf}
\Gls{oms}. 

%%%%%%



\end{document
```

}

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!!